# How can I put html tag into events Java script full calendar title?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I want put html tag from PHP side but
java script full calendar doing scape events title

```
            $data[]    = [
                "id"             => "reminder" . $item->id,
                "title"          => $item->title . "<a ref='test.png'>test</a>",
            ];

// output = testing title <a ref='test.png'>test</a>
```

Comment: fullcalendar will interpret the title data as plain text by default. If you want to put HTML content into the event display, you can use one of the [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) as per your need.

Answer (score 3):

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    eventContent: function (arg) {
        return { html: arg.event._def.title }
    },
});
```